# Restart WaWorkerHost on Azure (via RDP)

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, rdp

I have an Azure worker that works fine locally but crashes on live fabric. I want to hook up a remote debugger, but I can't because the program crashes before I can RDP in and attach a debugger.

Is there a way to manually restart `WaWorkerHost.exe` without restarting the system?

Answer (score 6):

You can kill WaWorkerHost, it will be restarted automatically by WaHostBootstrapper (just give it a minute).

---

Responding to your comment:

If I understand you correctly you should

- first deploy an empty worker (or one that does not crash)
- connect to your role instance (remote desktop)
- then deploy with the binaries you want to test.

Comment: WaHostBootstrapper only has a limited number of retries before it stops restarting it. By the time I can get in, its too late.

Answer (score 1):

A blog series on connecting debugger under azure (Putting here for other peoples reference I guess you have got this far)

http://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/2011/06/21/Remote-debugging-an-Azure-Worker-role-using-Azure-Connect-Remote-desktop-and-the-remote-debugger.aspx

Now to the problem at hand what I would surgest doing is getting your worker to suspend it self in the startup code until the debugger is attached and logging.

So you can just use the following property and method.  I would sleep the thred as well while waiting.

```
        while (!(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached && System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsLogging()))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't restart the service. It also doesn't let me work on a production instance.

Comment: I was thinking more of an alternative to restarting the actual worker.  You do this before any of your code so it will wait for the debugger to be ready so you can attach normally.  You can do this on a production instance providing it has been configured like in the above article this isn't for the emulator.